# How do I scroll an image programatically?

Tags: android, scroll, imageview, scrollview, android-animation

I'm attempting to place an image on the background of my UI.  The image is twice the height of my screen, as I intend to have it scroll automatically from top to bottom, and then stay there.  I've been researching ways to do this with ImageViews and ScrollViews, however every example assumes the use of users scrolling the image via an ontouch listener, and the use of scrollbars.  I on the other hand want to animate it programatically by iterating the X and Y values of the image with a defined wait delay to control the speed.

I'm still quite green when it comes to Android development, so I'm wondering if anyone can help me by suggesting the best method to achieve this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show some codes, screenshots and XML layout ?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, at this stage I have none as I'm first only after the suggested "best" method, and once I know that I can continue my research in that area.  I've been looking through the help pages for the various views, but so far have been unable to determine which is best.  I want to avoid trying to use a component for a purpose other than it was intended.  For all I know there is highly likely a simply method out there that does exactly what I'm after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found what I was looking for, so hopefully this is helpful to another Android newbie out there also.  What you're after is Tween Animation.  See the following link for more info and an example.  Note that the XML for the anim file is syntactically incorrect, you'll need to add the missing namespace property as per below:

Link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html

XML:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <scale
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="1.4"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="0.6"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:duration="700" />
    <set android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">
        <scale
           android:fromXScale="1.4"
           android:toXScale="0.0"
           android:fromYScale="0.6"
           android:toYScale="0.0"
           android:pivotX="50%"
           android:pivotY="50%"
           android:startOffset="700"
           android:duration="400"
           android:fillBefore="false" />
        <rotate
           android:fromDegrees="0"
           android:toDegrees="-45"
           android:toYScale="0.0"
           android:pivotX="50%"
           android:pivotY="50%"
           android:startOffset="700"
           android:duration="400" />
    </set>
</set>
```